# Issue converting NSData to UIImage via Parse.com download

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, uiimage, nsdata

I'm having a strange issue. My app works fine in the iPhone 6 emulator, but not in any other emulators or on my iDevice. Here's the main code

```
 query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects, error) -> Void in
        if(error == nil){


            let imageObjects = objects as! [PFObject]


            if let myObjects = objects {
                for object in myObjects {

                     let myTitle = object["imageName"] as! NSString
                     println(myTitle)
                    let thumbNail = object["imageFile"] as! PFFile
                   // println(thumbNail)
                thumbNail.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({
                        (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                        if (error == nil) {

                            self.imageArray.append(imageData!)
                            let image = UIImage(data:imageData!)

                            self.imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
                            self.imageView.image=image
                        }

                    })//getDataInBackgroundWithBlock - end

                }//for - end

            }

        }//end of if
        else{
            println("Error in retrieving \(error)")
        }

    }//findObjectsInBackgroundWithblock - end
```

I think this line is the culprit

```
let image = UIImage(data:imageData!)
```

But I'm not sure why. "image" returns nil in all other devices except iPhone 6 emulator. Any suggestions would be awesome.
Thanks

NOTE: the image displays just fine in iPhone 6 emulator. I'm using storyboard and unchecked autolayout.

Comment: Try resetting the simulator.

Comment: That did it! Thanks. I can't believe that was all I had to do and I'm embarrassed I didn't think of it myself. That's 2 hours I'll never get back :)

Comment: Fantastic! I'll go ahead and make that the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't really be a situation where the app only works on one simulator setting. Resetting your simulator should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that you previously successfully downloaded this data, and Parse has cached the response in your iPhone app, but you've since changed the PFObject remotely and removed the image data. Or perhaps changed code.

Because Parse.com caches images, it's possible that it works only on this device because of Parse.com caching.

You could use the debugger, or worse, NSLog to determine what is nil. You need to determine if `imageData` is coming back nil or not. Also, is there a reason why you're assuming imageData is non-null? I'm referring to references to `imageData!` -- that seems dangerous. Just because there's no error doesn't mean `imageData` is non-null.